# How to enable ConsistentRead on DynamoDB GetItem() in C++

Tags: c++, amazon-dynamodb

According to [Aws SDK documentation](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_dynamo_d_b_1_1_dynamo_d_b_client.html#a093472513a66879edfc33b0c7f0b0147), GetItem() provides an eventually consistent read by default. How do I set ConsistentRead to true to enable the strong consistent read in my code?

```
template<typename T>
bool DynamoDBClient::GetItemByKey(const std::string& table, const std::string& key_name, const std::string& key_value, const std::string& projection_expr, T& result) {
  Aws::SDKOptions options;
  options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Info;
  AWS::InitAPI(options);

  // Set up request.
  Aws::DynamoDB::Model::GetItemRequest gir;
  gir.SetTableName(String2AwsString(table));
  Aws::DynamoDB::Model::AttributeValue hashKey;
  hashKey.setS(String2AwsString(key_value));
  gir.AddKey(String2AwsString(key_name), hashKey);
  if (!projection_expr.empty()) {
    gir.SetProjectionExpression(projection_expr);
  }

  // Retrieve item from table.
  const Aws::DynamoDB::Model::GetItemOutcome& result = dynamodb_client_->GetItem(gir);
  ...
}
```

Comment: It looks like `GetItemRequest` has a [`WithConsistentRead`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_dynamo_d_b_1_1_model_1_1_get_item_request.html#a7cf0a1dc8e97e850617a05ab642119fa) method that seems like it'd do what you want. (it also has a `SetConsistentRead` method which appears to do the same thing, just not with a "fluent API").

Comment: @OliverDain Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As Oliver pointed out, the **ConsistentRead** flag can be enabled/disabled via GetItemRequest::SetConsistentRead() or GetItemRequestWithConsistentRead() methods as the follows:

```
// Set up request.
Aws::DynamoDB::Model::GetItemRequest gir;
gir.SetTableName(String2AwsString(table));
gir.SetConsistentRead(true);
```